# Will Processing without a Spatial Reference cause Issues?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system

I was given a bunch of ASCII files that I needed to convert to raster and then create maps from. For some maps I had to do a simple difference calculation between two rasters (did this in ArcMap).

Well, after I had created dozens of these maps I realized the rasters didn't have a spatial reference. The ASCII files all contain the same spatial extent in lat/lon and same cell size in degrees.  I thought to avoid any potential problems that may be caused by the lack of spatial reference, I would define the projection as WGS 84.

Would the lack of spatial reference have caused any problems when I did the difference calculations? I tried calculating the difference for a couple of sample files with and without a spatial reference and found no difference so I assume I can just add the spatial reference to my difference rasters that don't have a spatial reference instead of redoing them all.

Is this correct?

Comment: ASCII files (Esri ASCII grid) don't contain projection information only world translation. If you have only done differences between unreferenced rasters then there should be no problem - only if you have performed calculations against referenced data and their correct spatial reference differs from the assumed spatial reference (NAD I think, which is fairly much WGS84 for geographic).

Comment: Yes, I only calculated differences between rasters with no spatial reference (but they were all using the same coordinate system with the same extent and cell size).  I didn't do any calculations between referenced and non-referenced data.  Well, actually I did on one to just test if there was difference between the calculations using non-referenced vs referenced data and there wasn't.  Thanks so much for your response!

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine if it was consistently undefined in them all but they all really had the same coordinate system (just not defined).

Comment: Yes, all calculations were done on rasters that had the same coordinate system, same extent, and same cell size.  Thank you so much for your response!